# How do I send a process output to multiple channels in Nextflow?

Tags: pipeline, nextflow

I'm implementing a Nextflow workflow where each process can give multiple outputs that may be needed downstream on different processes.

```
process multiple_outputs {
   input:
   tuple id, input from previous_process

   output:
   tuple id, input_for_a, input_for_b, input_for_a_b into downstream
}
```

Nextflow documentation states that [operator into can use multiple channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#into) and [promotes channel duplication as a pattern](https://github.com/nextflow-io/patterns/blob/master/docs/channel-duplication.adoc).

However none of these options seems to work inside [the process primitive](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html?highlight=clause#multiple-output-files) and [multiple channel output is not documented](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html?highlight=clause#outputs):

- The pattern [found on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972302/nextflow-is-it-possible-to-tranform-a-queue-channel-to-a-value-channel?rq=1) (syntax error):

  ```
  output:
  tuple id, input_for_a, input_for_b, input_for_a_b into { downstream_a; downstream_b }
  // nor these variants:
  //
  // `into { downstream_a, downstream_b }`
  // `into downstream_a, downstream_b`
  // `into tuple a, b`
  ```
- Repeating the output into duplicated channels (one channel is empty):

  ```
  output:
  tuple id, input_for_a, input_for_a_b into downstream_a
  tuple id, input_for_b, input_for_a_b into downstream_b
  // runs, but cannot find the file in one of the channels
  ```

Which is the right way to use the output in multiple channels?

Answer (score 3):

The output declaration should be:

```
output:
tuple id, input_for_a, input_for_b, input_for_a_b into(downstream_a, downstream_b)
```

In alternative, you may want to consider using DLS2 which does not have anymore the single-channel usage requirement. Read more about it [here](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/edge/dsl2.html#channel-forking).

Answer (score 1):

Answer b seems to work:

```
output:
tuple id, input_for_a, input_for_a_b into downstream_a
tuple id, input_for_b, input_for_a_b into downstream_b
```

It seems that it failed for non related reasons.